# Visual Studio 2010 environment variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

I've set an environment variable named %SDK% in windows.
Can I use it somehow in .csproj file?

Something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="SomeDll">
    <HintPath>%SDK%\SomeDll.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I've tried %SDK% and $(SDK) and it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG, I had wrong path set in that variable.
It works with:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="SomeDll">
    <HintPath>$(SDK)\SomeDll.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Well, illustrative perhaps only to show what a bad idea it is to use environment variables.

Comment: Yes you're right. I left that idea, in favor of relative path.