# Visual Studio 2012 does not read environment variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# project that has bunch of environment variables in csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Name1">
       <HintPath>$(ENV_NAME1)\Name1.dll</HintPath>
     <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Name2">
      <HintPath>$(ENV_NAME2)\Name2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I've set this variables in my devbox, but when I load VS it does not find references dlls and does not build (I need to use these env variables only on compile time).  I have tried for a test using something common, like $(Program Files) with dll in there - does not work.

I tried to create bat files setting process environment variables and then calling VS but still no luck. I've looked through many questions on SO (in this, for example in [Visual Studio 2010 environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872644/visual-studio-2010-environment-variable) it seems to work). I've also seen a pretty old not-repro bug in http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/233464/use-environment-variables-in-hintpath about similar problem.

Is there a way to make VS read these environment variables from csproj file other that using absolute/relative paths?

Comment: $(Program Files) is not a valid environment variable. Not globally, not for msbuild. But even then we're going to need more info. You see, if i just put a line `<Message Text="$(Path)" />` in msbuild, it will correctly print the PATH environment variable, no matter how I call it, so msbuild normally handles this ok.. If you're on a commandline, what does `echo %ENV_NAME1%` print? What does `<Message Text="$(ENV_NAME1)" />` print in msbuild? If you run msbuild with the `/verbosity=diagnostic` swicth, do you see the variables there?

Comment: "I've set this variables in my devbox" is much too vague.  Otherwise a good reminder what a bad idea it is to rely on environment variables.  Use Control Panel + System to edit the environment.  Then logout + login to ensure the changes are seen by all processes.